# Copy non contiguous cells (h2,A5,E6,E11) from multiple workbooks and display row by row

Tags: excel, vba

I got 4 folders having Excels files in it. I want to copy non contiguous cells(A1,B4,C6,D8) from the different workbooks and paste it in main workbook. A1 represent date, B4 represent Name, C6 represent Age and D8 represent Address. Display row by row.

My code is displayed below:

```
Sub LoopFolders()
'Declare variabes
Dim myFolder As String
Dim mySubFolder As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim collSubFolders As New Collection
Dim myItem As Variant 'excel will decide what kind of variable that is
Dim wbk As Workbook


Dim copyRange As Range, cel As Range, pasteRange As Range


'Set the parent folder
myFolder = "C:\Users\sunvi\Desktop\test\FEB 19\"
'retrieve my subfolder using the directory function
mySubFolder = Dir(myFolder & "*", vbDirectory)
'Make our macro run faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Run a loop
Do While mySubFolder <> ""
'Use Select case statement
Select Case mySubFolder
'one dot refer to current folder/two dots refer to the parent folder
Case ".", ".." 'it would do nothing if it is the curent folder or parent folder.

Case Else
'add a folder(subfolder) to our collection

collSubFolders.Add Item:=mySubFolder  'add a item to our subfolder collection
End Select

'retrieve Next subfolder using the directory function without givig any parameter to the Dir function
mySubFolder = Dir
Loop ' do while loop


'loop through each subfolders in my collection of subfolders


For Each myItem In collSubFolders

'loop through excel workbooks in subfolders
myFile = Dir(myFolder & myItem & "\*.xlsm*")

'within this loop nested a do while loop
Do While myFile <> ""
'Open a workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myFolder & myItem & "\" & myFile)
'Defining the lastrow before copying data
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Defining the lastcolumn before copying data
lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


'we use the set keyword to create a new object
Set copyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("I2,D46,D47,D48,D49")

Set pasteRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FEB 18").Range("A1")


For Each cel In copyRange
cel.Copy
'erow defines the next blank row


'Once copy close workbook
wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False 'prevent data to chane from original workbook

'paste data in activeworksheet
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row 'offset(1,0) by one row
'ecolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Column

ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select

ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'pasteRange.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


'ActiveSheet.Paste


'ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("FEB 18").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))



Next '............................








ActiveWorkbook.Save

'remove the ant-like selection
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'get next file


myFile = Dir
Loop 'close do while


Next myItem 'close for loop
'Activate screenupdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain the issue you are currently having. Also, [indentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) would make this much easier to read.

Comment: copy non contiguous cells (h2,A5,E6,E11) from multiple workbooks and display row by row
excel-vba
Plse help???I got 4 folders having excels files in it.I want to copy non contiguous cells(A1,B4,C6,D8) from the different workbooks and paste it in main workbook.A1 represent date,B4 represent Name,C6 represent Age and D8 reprsent Address.display row by row.

Comment: @Vishals Note that it is not possible to throw in your code and tell *"please fix it"*, we need to know where exactly you got stuck or erros. Therefore you need to [edit] your question and improve it. Questions seeking debugging help (***"why isn't this code working?"***) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code is not working.It only display the data of I2 cell.Not able to display all the non contiguous cell data from different workbooks

Set copyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("I2,D46,D47,D48,D49")

Set pasteRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("masterWrkSheet").Range("A1")

For Each cel In copyRange

cel.Copy

wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False

erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row 
ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select

ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code is not working.It only display the data of I2 cell.Not able to display all the non contiguous cell data from different workbooks

Set copyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("I2,D46,D47,D48,D49")

Set pasteRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("masterWrkSheet").Range("A1")

For Each cel In copyRange

cel.Copy

wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False

erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select

ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next